# PHP and Paypal redirect by link

Tags: php, paypal

Hi stackers i got a question about paypal and linking. Is there way to generate link to paypal with thouse data:

```
$payment_Id = generateRandomString();
$currency = $_POST['currency'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$trip = $_POST['trip'];
```

I want to create order that client can pay for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But you really, **really** need to automatically or manually verify the right amount was paid though (i.e. via PayPal [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn)).
But you can get paid via PayPal as easily as simply create a link and appending `GET` params to it:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=youremail@goeshere.tld&amount=1.00&currency_code=GBP&item_name=tripdatagoeshere

Alternatively, feel free to use the above params and send them to us via `POST`. As long as you send them to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

If you're interested, we've got lots more variables available for use at [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).